# Sencha Touch cordova.local.properties is missing

Tags: cordova, windows-phone-8, sencha-touch, sencha-cmd, sencha-cmd5

I am using Sencha CMD 5.1.0.26, Sencha Touch 2.4.0 and cordova 4.0.

Steps I did:

1. sencha -sdk /senchapath generate app MyApp MyApp
2. cd MyApp
3. sencha cordova init com.test.MyApp

After Step 3, no cordova.local.properties was generated.

I opened app.json and uncommented the platforms
"platforms": "wp8 android",

I copied the file from other project to MyApp and changed the the platforms=android
also did the 
Step 4.  sencha ant cordova-sencha-prepare

and I got another error

> Target "cordova-sencha-prepare" does not exist in the project

I do have android and wp8 environments set up in my system.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since Sencha CMD 5.X,  the package.json and cordova.local.properties are not required anymore.

I created my app by following this article:

http://docs.sencha.com/cmd/5.x/cordova_phonegap.html